# Regex extract between u''

Tags: regex

I'm new with regex, how do I extract values between u''?

```
[u'value1', u'value2', u'value3']
```

thanks

Comment: You are expected to at least make an attempt. Let us know what you have tried and what issues you are having with your attempt (errors, what is matching, what isn't). Also, what language are you trying to do this with? Different regex engines can behave differently. I suggest using a site like https://regex101.com/ and playing around to see what you can do.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I should have posted my trials. I've been getting crazy for hours, tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746395/java-regex-content-between-single-quotes with no luck. I could manage to extract only the first value. I'm doing it in Google Spreadsheet using regexextract() formula. Now I changed approach using sniperd reply. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to regex.  Looks like you have a list where each is item is Unicode, that's what that u usually means if this is Python (looks like it might be?)  If you simply loop the list and print it out the u won't be there.

```
import re

thelist = [u'value1', u'value2', u'value3']

for item in thelist:
    print (item)
```

results:

```
value1
value2
value3
```